# Pass model name as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view where I pass the model name to populate it, is there any way to pass model name as a parameter based on the controller action executed?

```
<div id = "Details" >

<% List<Freshmen>() = model based on controller action executed %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("FreshmenDetails", "Students")) %>
        <% { %>
<%  Html.RenderPartial("FreshmenDetails", new List<Freshmen>()); %>
        <% } %>
</div>
```

Controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult FreshmenDetails(string id)
    {
        DataContext Student = new DataContext();
        var FreshmenDetails = Student.Freshmen.Where(a => Convert.ToInt64(a.Id) == Convert.ToInt64(id)).ToList();

        return PartialView("FreshmenDetails", FreshmenDetails );
    }
```

I have 3 more Actions each for SophomoreDetails(),JuniorDetails(),SeniorDetails()

Currently I am displaying Partial View like this:

```
<div id = "Details" >

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("FreshmenDetails", "Students")) %>
        <% { %>
<%  Html.RenderPartial("FreshmenDetails", new List<Freshmen>()); %>
        <% } %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("SophomoreDetails", "Students")) %>
        <% { %>
<%  Html.RenderPartial("SophomoreDetails", new List<Sophomore>()); %>
        <% } %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("JuniorDetails", "Students")) %>
        <% { %>
<%  Html.RenderPartial("JuniorDetails", new List<Junior>()); %>
        <% } %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("SeniorDetails", "Students")) %>
        <% { %>
<%  Html.RenderPartial("SeniorDetails", new List<Senior>()); %>
        <% } %>
</div>
```

I want something like:

```
<div id = "Details" >
```

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("FreshmenDetails", "Students")) %>
        <% { %>
<%  Html.RenderPartial("FreshmenDetails", new List<Freshmen>()); %>
        <% } %>

</div>
```

Comment: Post your Model and your Controller Action.

Comment: @Pluc I have multiple partial views which are displayed at the same location but have different Controller,Action and Model. I was able to parameterize Controller and Action names but struggling with parameterizing model, looking for an efficient way to passing these to partial view . Can this be achieved?

Comment: @ataravati Updated above

Comment: Your question still makes no sense

Comment: Why do you have such abstract names for your objects? It's so confusing. And, it's not clear what you want to do with your Model. What do you mean by this code: `<% List<ModelName>() = model name based on controller action executed %>`?

Comment: @ataravati I pass the model name in my view like this: 
Html.RenderPartial("DisplayDetails", new List<FreshmenStudents>());
I am looking to parameterize "<FreshmenStudents>"

Comment: That's not your Model Name, it's your Model. Why do you post a code in your original question, and a different one in your comment? You did the same thing in you other question. So, your Model is no ModelName, it's List<FresnmenStudents>, and you want to reuse the same action/view for a different Model like List<JuniorStudents>. Am I right?

Comment: Please post the real code you are working on.

Comment: @ataravati I want to reuse the same view, but the actions are different. There are four links(Freshmen, Sophomore, Junior, Senior) which invoke four different actions(FreshmenDetails, SophomoreDetails, JuniorDetails, SeniorDetails). So if you click on "Freshmen" link it will trigger "FreshmenDetails" Action and display details in a partial view. Same for all others. This partial view is displayed on another strongly typed view.

Comment: OK, then, you'll have to create a separate partial view for each. I assume that each Model has its own specific properties that need to be displayed on the View. You can't create a Generic partial view.

Comment: @ataravati ok, got it. I was confusing myself and others too. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am having a hard time figuring out exactly what your after. That being said, have you tried using reflection?

```
return PartialView(Model.GetType().Name, new { // Partial View object });
```

Further more, you can use `Model.GetType().Name` to get the model object name and use it where you want.
That should work for you.